# Transform RDD to valid input for kmeans

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, k-means, apache-spark-mllib, tf-idf

I am calculating TF and IDF using spark mllib algorithm of a directory that contains csv files with the following code:

```python
import argparse
from os import system

### args parsing
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='runs TF/IDF on a directory of 
text docs')
parser.add_argument("-i","--input", help="the input in HDFS",  
required=True)
parser.add_argument("-o", '--output', help="the output in  HDFS", 
required=True )
parser.add_argument("-mdf", '--min_document_frequency', default=1 )
args = parser.parse_args()


docs_dir = args.input
d_out = "hdfs://master:54310/" + args.output
min_df = int(args.min_document_frequency)

# import spark-realated stuff
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.mllib.feature import HashingTF
from pyspark.mllib.feature import IDF

sc = SparkContext(appName="TF-IDF")

# Load documents (one per line).
documents = sc.textFile(docs_dir).map(lambda title_text: 
title_text[1].split(" "))

hashingTF = HashingTF()
tf = hashingTF.transform(documents)

# IDF
idf = IDF().fit(tf)
tfidf = idf.transform(tf)

#print(tfidf.collect())

#save
tfidf.saveAsTextFile(d_out)
```

Using

```python
print(tfidf.collect())
```

I get this output:

```python
[SparseVector(1048576, {812399: 4.3307}), SparseVector(1048576, {411697: 
0.0066}), SparseVector(1048576, {411697: 0.0066}), SparseVector(1048576, 
{411697: 0.0066}), SparseVector(1048576, {411697: 0.0066}), ....
```

I have also tested the KMeans mllib algorithm :

```python
from __future__ import print_function

import sys

import numpy as np
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.mllib.clustering import KMeans

runs=4

def parseVector(line):
return np.array([float(x) for x in line.split(' ')])

if __name__ == "__main__":
if len(sys.argv) != 3:
    print("Usage: kmeans <file> <k>", file=sys.stderr)
    exit(-1)
sc = SparkContext(appName="KMeans")
lines = sc.textFile(sys.argv[1])
data = lines.map(parseVector)
k = int(sys.argv[2])
model = KMeans.train(data, k, runs)
print("Final centers: " + str(model.clusterCenters))
print("Total Cost: " + str(model.computeCost(data)))
sc.stop()
```

with this sample test case

```python
0.0 0.0 0.0
0.1 0.1 0.1
0.2 0.2 0.2
9.0 9.0 9.0
9.1 9.1 9.1
9.2 9.2 9.2
```

and it works fine.

Now I want to apply the rdd output from tfidf above in the KMeans algorithm but I don't know how is it possible to transform the rdd like the sample text above, or how to split properly the rdd in the KMeans algorithm to work properly.

I really need some help with this one.

**UPDATE**

My real question is how can i read the input to apply it to KMeans mllib from a text file like this

```python
(1048576,[155412,857472,756332],[1.75642010278,2.41857747478,1.97365255252])
(1048576,[159196,323305,501636],[2.98856378408,1.63863706713,2.44956728334])
(1048576,[135312,847543,743411],[1.42412015238,1.58759872958,2.01237484818])
```

**UPDATE2**

I am not sure at all but i think i need to go from above vectors to the below array so as to apply it directly to KMeans mllib algorithm

```python
1.75642010278 2.41857747478 1.97365255252
2.98856378408 1.63863706713 2.44956728334
1.42412015238 1.58759872958 2.01237484818
```

Answer (score 1):

The output of IDF is a dataframe of `SparseVector`. KMeans takes a vector as input (sparse or dense), hence, there should be no need to make any transformations. You should be able to use the output column from IDF directly as input to KMeans.

If you need to save the data to disk in between running the TFIDF and KMeans, I would recommend saving it as a csv through the dataframe API.

First convert to a dataframe using `Row`:

```
from pyspark.sql import Row

row = Row("features")    # column name
df = tfidf.map(row).toDF()
```

An alternative way to convert without import:

```
df = tfidf.map(lambda x: (x, )).toDF(["features"])
```

After the conversion save the dataframe as a parquet file:

```
df.write.parquet('/path/to/save/file')
```

To read the data, simply use:

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

df = sqlContext.read.parquet('/path/to/file')

# converting from dataframe into an RDD[Vector]
data = df.rdd.map(list)
```

---

If you in any case need to convert from a vector saved as a string, that is also possible. Here is some example code:

```
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import Vectors, VectorUDT
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

df = sc.parallelize(["(7,[1,2,4],[1,1,1])"]).toDF(["features"])

parse = udf(lambda s: Vectors.parse(s), VectorUDT())
df.select(parse("features"))
```

First an example dataframe is created with the same formatting. Then an `UDF` is used to parse the string into a vector. If you want an rdd instead of the dataframe, use the code above at the "reading from parquet" part to convert.

---

However, the output from `IDF` is very sparse. The vectors have a length of 1048576 and only one of these have a values over 1. KMeans would not give you any interesting results.

I would recommend you to look into [word2vec](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.1/mllib-feature-extraction.html#word2vec) instead. It will give you a more compact vector for each word and clustering these vectors would make more sense. Using this method you can receive a map of words to their vector representations which can be used for clustering.